# Correct way send Firebase token to server when user try login/signUp

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) in my Android app. I need next:

1. User open app and if
2. app get login and md5 password from sharedPreferences and try login
3. if login successful - user enters to mainActivity else
4. if login error - user enters to Login Screen
5. User input login and password and press login button
6. if successful - user enters to mainActivity and login and password(md5) store in sharedPreferences. else user see an error and can login more and more

OR

7. The user can open signup screen and create a new profile with new login and password
8. User tries to sign up and if successful - user enters to mainActivity and login and password(md5) store in sharedPreferences. else User get an error

It is typical logic for Android app. But I do not understand how can I add Firebase to this logic.

When My app starts I have not `FirebaseInstanceId` and I get to only in `onTokenRefresh` (`async`). But when User tries login I need to pass this id(token) to the server. I have some ways:

1. When user open the app - I wait some time and after that get token and send with login and password - I think it is very bad practice.
2. I save token tosharedPreferens in `onTokenRefresh`. And when I try login I check this token. If the token is empty - I throw an exception and open login screen(). By this time, the token will come to the device and the user will try to log in again. - I think it is bad practice too.
3. When User tries login I send only login and password to the server. And when I get token - I send it to the server in another request. - I do not like as that will be two requests.

How to do it all right?

A many time ago I used this approach (when all used GSM):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    CloudMessaging.getInstance(this).retrieveRegistrationId(new CloudMessaging.RegistrationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRegistrationReceive(String registrationId) {

            savePushToken(registrationId);
            //open activity
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I was waiting when I get token and after that opened activity. But in Firebase - everything is different

Now I make this:

```
@Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "FCM Token: " + token);
        utils.saveToken(token);
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(FRIENDLY_ENGAGE_TOPIC);  
    }
```

and when users try to log in - I get token from storage and send to server with login and password.

UPDATE:

I did not quite understand the last paragraph. Now I see such logic.

1 - I open the application and go to the screen to enter a login and password. At this point, I do not know if I have a token or it's a null.

Therefore, I try to enter in any case. And if successfully logged in - I check in sharedPreferences whether there is a token and if it then sends it to the server. if not - then he will send from another place (from onTokenRefresh method). In onTokenRefresh method, When I get new token - I save it to sharedPreferences and check authToken. if authToken is not null (it means that I logged in) - I send the new token to server else only save to sharedPreferences. And send after success logged in. Make sense?

Comment: you try pushing the token during the login api / signup api

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would go for your second option where you save the token to Shared Preferences and then access it upon successfully signing in.

However, provided you're saving it to Shared Preferences correctly, it should not be null. The only way it would be null is if there was a problem with the FCM set up within your app which shouldn't be a limitation to your users logging in as this could be fixed with an update, your users might just have to live without FCM for a short amount of time...

It's quite common that the FCM token is sent in a separate request. From [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-device#access_the_registration_token), it states that the token is generated upon initial startup.

Also another point unrelated to your question, if you're storing an MD5 hash of the user's password on the device, you should also be hashing it and using salts upon reaching the server. You didn't mention anything about this but it raised a flag to me when you said about storing the users' password on the device.

If you're really keen to learn more about security, have a look at [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/).

Answer (score 0):

> *When My app start I have not FirebaseInstanceId and I get ot only in onTokenRefresh (async).*

If I understand this correctly, you are expecting that the token will only be generated in the `onTokenRefresh()`. This is true for most cases, but the behavior is that, as soon as you call `getToken()` -- presumably in your MainActivity, there will be two scenarios: it returns the token immediately, or it returns null.

For the first case, you can immediately just send the token to your preferred app server. If it is null, the `onTokenRefresh()` would then trigger, giving you the option to send it as you please.

The `onTokenRefresh()` only triggers when it detects that there is a new token -- in your use-case, what you currently have is actually the usual way to go -- separate requests for sending the user details and the token -- which in most cases, shouldn't be kept on the same level of importance. i.e. sign in credentials are critically important.

Comment: I supplemented the question. Look here please

Answer (score -1):

From Firebase Docs you get registration tokens:

The registration token may change when:

-The app deletes Instance ID

-The app is restored on a new device

-The user uninstalls/reinstall the app

-The user clears app data.